# Executing script (command against external database) after AX Entity export

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-365-operations

I'm working on a project to create an external data warehouse using some data from Microsoft Dynamics AX 7.  I am using the new BYOD approach which allows you to define an external database, and then use that database as the target when exporting one or more Dynamics entities.

See:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dynamicsaxbi/2016/07/27/export-dynamics-ax7-entities-to-your-own-azure-sql-database/

At the time of writing, this export mechanism is able to do incremental exports (only inserted or updated records) but it lacks support for record deletions.

With AX7 you cannot directly access the AX database from external systems, so what I'm wanting to do is run a post-export SQL script that will examine the MSSQL Change Tracking tables and based on that data for deleted rows, execute a series of delete systems on the same external database.

If it is possible, I'm hoping to use this more generic, sql-centric approach rather than getting involved in writing custom AX entities and export code.

How might one best approach this?

Comment: For reference, we've discussed this in the [Dynamics Community forum](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/251327). And yes, adding more logic to the standard batch running the export is possible.

Comment: I have to find out what it is I need to learn in order to accomplish this task.  Often software has some sort of "run this script after" functionality so that the user can accomplish most anything else not handled natively but that seems not to be the case with Dynamics.  So,  what *is* the way to do this?